# how to retrieve userId from membership users table

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm new to membership. i have a table named contact, with a field, userId that must get its data from the membership users table. so when a user is created i have to get the userId from membership users table. how can i do that?
thanx in advance

Comment: Are you talking about the [ASP.NET membership provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx) or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ProviderUserKey property of the MembershipUser object:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.provideruserkey.aspx

So say:

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.CreateUser("foo","password");
user.ProviderUserKey
```